# Converting between Cocoa and Carbon coordinates?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-carbon

I am looking for a robust (I mean working in all multi-munitor configuration) algo to convert a cocoa point/rect to carbon equivalent and the reverse operation.

I've googled but was unable to find something which work properly.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,

Comment: What is "the Carbon equivalent"? IIRC, Carbon had multiple point and rect types (I specifically remember Point, Rect, HIPoint, HIRect and CGPoint and CGRect). And how does a general point conversion algorithm "work in all multi-monitor configuration"? Are we talking converting local NSPoints into global HIPoints or what?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, I was meaning from top left origin to bottom left origin.

Answer (score 4):

After several iterations I got to the following category on `NSScreen`:

```
+ (NSScreen*) screenWithPoint: (NSPoint) p
{
    for (NSScreen *candidate in [NSScreen screens])
        if (NSPointInRect(p, [candidate frame]))
            return candidate;
    return nil;
}

+ (NSScreen*) screenWithMenuBar
{
    return [self screenWithPoint:NSZeroPoint];
}

+ (float) menuScreenHeight
{
    return NSMaxY([[self screenWithMenuBar] frame]);
}

+ (CGPoint) carbonPointFrom: (NSPoint) cocoaPoint
{
    return CGPointMake(cocoaPoint.x, [self menuScreenHeight] - cocoaPoint.y);
}

+ (NSPoint) cocoaPointFrom: (CGPoint) carbonPoint
{
    return NSMakePoint(carbonPoint.x, [self menuScreenHeight] - carbonPoint.y);
}
```

This works fine even with multiple displays.

Comment: This post explains how to add a category to NSScreen: http://commanigy.com/blog/2011/1/14/how-to-get-display-name-from-nsscreen

Answer (score 1):

The posted code from Apple's code from UIElementInspector turn out to be buggy, in that it doesn't account for the origin of a non-main screen. The fixed (and refactored) code looks like this:

```
+ (CGPoint)carbonScreenPointFromCocoaScreenPoint:(NSPoint)cocoaPoint {
  NSScreen* foundScreen = nil;
  NSRect screenFrame;
  for (NSScreen* screen in [NSScreen screens]) {
    screenFrame = [screen frame];
    if (NSPointInRect(cocoaPoint, screenFrame)) {
      foundScreen = screen;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (! foundScreen) return CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
  return CGPointMake(cocoaPoint.x, 
    screenFrame.origin.y + screenFrame.size.height - cocoaPoint.y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or take Apple's code from UIElementInspector sample project:

```
+ (CGPoint)carbonScreenPointFromCocoaScreenPoint:(NSPoint)cocoaPoint
{
    NSScreen *foundScreen = nil;
    CGPoint thePoint;

    for (NSScreen *screen in [NSScreen screens])
    {
        if (NSPointInRect(cocoaPoint, [screen frame]))
        {
            foundScreen = screen;
        }
    }

    if (foundScreen)
    {
        CGFloat screenHeight = [foundScreen frame].size.height;
        thePoint = CGPointMake(cocoaPoint.x, screenHeight - cocoaPoint.y - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        thePoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
    }

    return thePoint;
}
```